# Javascript - multidimensional associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I would like to know (if it's possible) how I can push data into a multidimensional associative array with JavaScript like this:

```
myarray['type1']['label1'].push('Data to insert');
myarray['type1']['label1'].push('Data2 to insert');
myarray['type1']['label1'].push('Data3 to insert');


myarray['type2']['label1'].push('Data to insert');
myarray['type2']['label2'].push('Data1 to insert');
myarray['type2']['label2'].push('Data2 to insert');
```

Here is the answer thanks to Brennan:

```
myarray = {};
myarray['type1'] = {};
myarray['type1']['label1'] = [];
myarray['type1']['label1'].push('Data to insert');
myarray['type1']['label1'].push('Data2 to insert');
myarray['type1']['label1'].push('Data3 to insert');

console.log(myarray);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/177zu9n4/

Thanks a lot.

Comment: create an array.. and push to IT

Comment: Make sure that you do this first... `myarray['type1']['label1'] = []`

Comment: [**Stop abusing arrays!!!**](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)

Answer (score 3):

First, there needs to be an array there to push the data into:

```
myarray = {};
myarray['type1'] = {};
myarray['type1']['label1'] = [];
myarray['type1']['label1'].push('Data to insert');
myarray['type1']['label1'].push('Data2 to insert');
myarray['type1']['label1'].push('Data3 to insert');
```

Comment: @SofianeSadi: [no it's not](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/)

Comment: Indeed. This is not how how you should build your 'associative arrays'. An "associative array" should be a javascript object, which is used exactly for key value named pairs. Edited my answer to be more clear @SofianeSadi

Comment: @Bergi i cant think of any valid reason in JS to use an assoc array over an obj can you ?!

Comment: @Pogrindis: The point is that there are no associative arrays, yes :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
myarray= {};
myarray.type1= {};
myarray.type1.label1= "Data to insert";

console.log(myarray.type1.label1);
```

Is this what you need?
If label1 is somehow meant to hold stuff too, as an array:

```
myarray= {};
myarray.type1= {};
myarray.type1.label1= [];

myarray.type1.label1.push("data");

console.log(myarray.type1.label1);
```

Note that I used both object and arrays in the last example, and only objects in the first. Each have case-specific uses they are better at.